# How do I redirect traffic to different ports on my machine based on the URL they are connecting with?

Tags: redirects, google-domains, srv-records

I have a web server (`www.2darkpark.net`) that I also host several game servers on - Minecraft, QuakeWorld, and Quake III. I would like to allow users to connect to the game servers through subdomains rather than entering ports. (ie, `q3.2darkpark.net` for Quake III as opposed to `www.2darkpark.net:27960`) With Minecraft, I was able to just use an SRV record to redirect traffic to the port. (`25565`) However, QuakeWorld and Quake III do not appear to support SRV redirects. What else can I do?

My domain is registered through Google Domains and my server is running Ubuntu Server 20.04.

Comment: Is using the default port not an option for some reason?

Comment: It *almost* is, but I'm also running a *modded* Quake 3 server alongside the normal one which runs on a non-default port. Plus I just wanna know how this works - if it does.